# Как не учитывать отдельные папки в url в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Подскажите, пожалуйста, у меня в подпапках worpress лежат скрипты, которые не нужно учитывать в постоянных ссылках wordpress. Т.е. есть worpdress сайт site.ru. Есть, например, папка со скриптами, которая не относятся к wp - site.ru/script .
Но при переходе на неё выкидывает на 404 ошибку. В WP включены постоянные ссылки - название записи + плагин транслитерация кириллицы. Как решить это?

Comment: ВП и так ничего не знает ни о  папках ни о мамках ни даже о каталогах, которые ему не принадлежат. Если получаешь ВПшную 404 значит такого файла либо физически не существует.либо он не доступен.

Comment: @SeVlad, действительно, проблема была в недоступности скрипта, попробовал другой путь - всё заработало. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо изменить .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/excluded-folder/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

где excluded-folder - название Вашей директории